# PHP - string to html

Tags: php, html

I have got an array of strings in php. It looks like this:

```
$array = ['text-1' => '<p>Hello</p><span class="my-custom-class">random text here</span>'];
```

When I echo it into my html, it does not transfer tags into html but displays it as it is in the array. How could I transfer it to html?

Thank you for any kind of advice

Comment: How are you outputting it?

Comment: That should be a security precaution

Comment: If you're seeing the tags in the web page, it sounds like the array actually contains HTML entity codes, not the HTML you show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

here we go

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<!--begin $key-->".$value."<!-- end $key -->";
}
```

or if you like to buffer stuff up to push one big write

```
$output = "";
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $output .= "<!--begin $key-->".$value."<!-- end $key -->";
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$array = array('text' => '<p>Hello</p><span class="my-custom-class">random text here</span>');
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo htmlentities($value);
}
```